# async on google app engine for scala?

Tags: google-app-engine, scala

The new (experimental, open sourced) python API for google app engine makes sophisticated use of Python's async capabilities to conveniently allow overlapped operations: http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2011/01/new-app-engine-datastore-api.html. What hoops would I have to jump through to achieve the same thing using Scala (or maybe some other JVM language)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Java Async Datastore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async.html). If you want to make it more 'scala-esque', you'll probably need to write the wrapper yourself.